# Servlet Filter url-mapping /* is not working on 404 errors

Tags: java, apache, servlet-filters, resin

I'm using Resin Server & Apache 2.2 with virtual hosting.
Here I'm facing a big challenge in calling a concrete filter. 
I'm having a generic Filter class to process all the incoming request.

Ex: www.example.com/hello this hello is not calling the below filter instead it throwing file not found error(404).

If "hello" is having a proper servlet mapping then the below filter is working.

**Web.xml :**

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorpFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.filter.CorpFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Apache Log :**

> [Fri Jan 04 22:05:07 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]  File does
>   not exist: /home/xxxx/public_html/hello

Why the servlet filter is not being called and throwing 404 error?
Servlet filter is initializing properly.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong in the `CorpFilter` and this filter failed to start.Then when you tried to access some other url-patterns ,system tried to locate `CorpFilter` first but failed .I don't think your filter is initialized properly.

Answer (score 3):

Filters are by default dispatched on successful requests. They are by default not dispatched on erroneous requests. In order to dispatch them on erroneous requests as well, expand the filter mapping with the appropriate `<dispatcher>` elements:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Note that when specifying custom dispatcher types and you'd like to *keep* the default `REQUEST` dispatcher, then you should be explicitly specifying it as well. Note that I also assume that the 404 is not handled by the web proxy (Apache HTTPD), but by the servlet container (Resin) itself, for obvious reasons.

Comment: As you said I have added the above code unfortunately still it is throwing 404 error. If I change the filter to "*.JSP" then it catching all the JSP files. Even I've removed my .htaccess file to test this, I'm having CentOS with Apache 2.2 and Resin 3.1.12.