# Catching 404s (and other server errors?) using Filter

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, servlet-filters

I'm not sure if this question has been already asked here or not, the best duplicate I could find is [Servlet Filter url-mapping /* is not working on 404 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181731/servlet-filter-url-mapping-is-not-working-on-404-errors)

But that doesn't solve my problem.

I'm using Jetty 9 and I have a filter something like this  -

```
@WebFilter(dispatcherTypes = { DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR }, urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class ErrorHandler implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        int errorcode = HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        String message = "";
        boolean error = false;

        StringWriter sw_stacktrace = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw_stacktrace = new PrintWriter(sw_stacktrace);

        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (AppException e) {
            errorcode = e.getCode();
            error = true;
            message = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace(pw_stacktrace);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            error = true;
            message = "Unknown Error";
            t.printStackTrace(pw_stacktrace);
        }

        if (!response.isCommitted()) {
            if (error) {
                if (errorcode == HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) {
                    String log = String.format("Error %d Occurred - \n %s \n Stack Trace - \n %s", errorcode, message, sw_stacktrace.toString());
                    request.getServletContext().log(log);
                }

                HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                resp.setStatus(errorcode);
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", message);
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message"));
            }
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/templates/error/" + errorcode + ".jsp").forward(request, response);          
        }
        pw_stacktrace.close();
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

    }
}
```

I'm using it for catching a custom exception type (subclass of `ServletException`) and any other exceptions that occur during run time (null pointer, etc) to show an error page -- it's working perfectly.

But for some reason, my filter doesn't get called for 404s.
I tried the `web.xml` method too as mentioned in the question I linked, but that doesn't work either.

I'm new to Java and all this stuff.. I may be trying the wrong thing here, but what exactly is the use of `DispatcherType.ERROR` if the filter is not supposed to catch all kinds of errors? I know it's possible to configure custom error pages as described at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/custom-error-pages.html

just curious about this thing.

Answer (score 0):

So, the thing is, 404 is not really an exception. Filters marked with `DispatcherType.ERROR` are invoked when I set `<error-page>` in `web.xml`.